# Image caption on Tumblr Text posts

Tags: html, css, image, tumblr, caption

On a Tumblr Post, if they are Image posts, the caption is placed below the Image.

I can´t find how to do it on a text posts, and thus we are forced to place an italic paragraph below the image.

i.e.
http://news.gain.org/post/23115584298/adaptation-is-essential-global-decision-makers

Any ideas?

I´ve the impression I have to edit the HTML of the Theme, but I can´t find where.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to http://www.tumblr.com/customize and press “Edit HTML”

[here](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photo-posts) is tumblr wiki for photo posts

P.S. Tumblr has no opportunity to add a special caption for images in text posts. For more flexibility styling you can add paragraph with custom class (e.g. `.photo-caption`) and control it with `css` code like this:

```
.photo-caption {
    font-style: italic;
    /* or some other decoration, 
       which will be applied for all image-caption
       in all your posts */
}
```

and paste it in 'Custom CSS' field on the same [customize page](http://www.tumblr.com/customize)

Comment: Easy: in theory text posts are not intended to get images in them: *that's what photo posts are for*. Yeah, it's a lot less flexible than they make it out to be.